# Getting Uncaught TypeError but link works fine

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Although there are some questions  similar, ive read it and cant solve my problem.
Hope someone direct some light on this in order to help  not only me but others out there.

I have added JS file to my child theme (wordpress) via functions.php and then added Event listener to ID.

The problem inhabits on the :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at custom.js?ver=5.4:1

Although when i click the object it goes correctly to the link, the error shows on console.

on functions.php ive added:

function my_customm_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_customm_scripts' );

and in my custom.js ive added:

```
document.getElementById('hercule').addEventListener('click', function() {
    location.href = 'https://somedomain.com'
}, false);
```

im shure its straightforward but ive checked so many solutions without success
Thx for your time
J.

[image]

```html
 <div class="hoverfora wpb_animate_when_almost_visible wpb_slideInUp slideInUp wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4 wpb_start_animation animated" id="hercule">
  <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1587337223984">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
      <div class="service_table_holder">
        <ul class="service_table_inner">
          <li class="service_table_title_holder background_color_type" style="">
            <div class="service_table_title_inner">
              <div class="service_table_title_inner2">
                <h3 class="service_title" style="">Web design</h3>
                  <i class="qode_icon_font_awesome fa fa-desktop fa-3x" style="color: #efcd21 !important;"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="service_table_content" style="">Development de websites .
              <p></p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code of yours:

```
document.getElementById('hercule')
```

is looking for a DOM element with `id="hercule"`. Apparently, your page does not contain such an element at the time the `custom.js` is being run, so `document.getElementById('hercule')` is returning null, then a TypeError is thrown when `addEventListener` method is called on a null object.

Look for an element on your HTML page that contains `id="hercule"`. If you can't find it, your problem has been identified.

**Edit:**

Subsequent information reveals that the custom.js JavaScript is trying to access a div with id="hercule" before it exists. The solution is to delay the start of the custom function until the div exists.

Normally, waiting for the window's `load` event is sufficient, but it is unclear in this case that will work, as "hercule" may be generated by another JavaScript function that won't complete by the time of the `load` event.

One solution is simply to continue to look for "hercule" until it's found:

```js
// USE THIS SECTION IN YOUR CODE:

// keep looking for "hercule"
function lookForHercule() {
  const hercule = document.getElementById('hercule');
  if (hercule) {
    // add the 'click' listener to 'hercule'
    hercule.addEventListener('click', function() {
      hercule.innerHTML = "You clicked hercule, redirecting to somedomain.com";
      location.href = 'https://somedomain.com'
      }, false);
    return;
  }
  console.log('"hercule" not found');
  setTimeout(lookForHercule, 2000);
}

// start looking
lookForHercule();

// END OF SECTION TO USE IN YOUR CODE

// THE CODE BELOW IS FOR THIS DEMO ONLY, DO NOT USE IN YOUR CODE:

// FOR DEMO ONLY:
// add 'hercule' after 10 seconds to simulate delay
setTimeout(() => {
  const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
  const hercule = document.createElement('div');
  hercule.id = 'hercule';
  hercule.innerHTML = "I am hercule. Clicking me will redirect to somedomain.com";
  wrapper.appendChild(hercule);
}, 10000);
```

```css
/* this will change cursor to finger when hovering over hercule */
#hercule:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <h4>Search for 'hercule'</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Terrymorse, Thx so much in advance. But i do have the id in my div in html..

Comment: Terry, it works the link. but the error shows. if was no id on page , it would never work the link

Comment: how do i add a photo here?

Comment: added Mr Terry Morse and image too

Comment: @SalOx pay close attention to _"your page does not contain such an element **at the time** the `custom.js` is being run"_

Comment: Thanks Mr Phil. i understand . How can we fix that?

Comment: @SalOx Fix the problem by delaying your `custom.js` function from running until the DOM is complete.

Comment: Mr Terrymorse, Thx so much for the time you spent on trying to incept a solution. The alert says in fact id hercules exists, but that we already knew. regarding the second part , creating an element its not the best way, cause the id hercules is already there. Again i really appreciate your effort, but i give up this since theres no solution. Best regards, J

Comment: I can't cause im in close enviroment. bur your code gives me : Uncaught TypeError: wrapper.appendChild is not a function
    at lookForHercule

Comment: i'm using: const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('hoverfora');
 const hercule = document.createElement('div');
 hercule.id = 'hercule';
 hercule.innerHTML = "I am hercule.";
 wrapper.appendChild(hercule);

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: wrapper.appendChild is not a function

Comment: sorry for incapacity to go further in JavaScript since im a beginner on that subject. That's why i asked for your help , you guys know so much.

Comment: You copied the demo code in addition to the working code. See the comments I just added to the code, they should help you select the right code.

Comment: Mr TerryMorse, again Thx so much for being there. im shore u have more useful ways to spend your time  rather than helping those who knows little about JS.   regarding css im good. Anyway ive used the section u provided in my JS file. As since day one th eelemnt id #hercule works fine and redirects me to the domain i want..no big issue there. but now instead of giving that former error, it says: [Violation] 'DOMContentLoaded' handler took 322ms and ofc it shows every 2 secs as defined the message on console:"hercule" not found. SO , can i ignore that error since the link works?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is

```
window.location.href = 'https://somedomain.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

If you are sure that your html source contains the element with id="hercule". Then you can try

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('hercule').addEventListener('click', function() {
        location.href = 'https://somedomain.com'
        // alert("clicked div");
    }, false);
};
```

Make sure that all your onload processes are written in a single place. Otherwise the browser will keep and execute only last found window.onload function.

Comment: To avoid overwriting an existing `window.onload`, you can use `window.addEventListener('load', fn)`.

Comment: the proble persists. that didnt make the cut. Thx anyway mate.